# Simulating the probability that Alice and Bob flip the same number of tails

Tags: r, simulation

> Alice tosses a fair coin n independent times and Bob tosses a fair
>   coin m independent times. What is the probability that they have equal
>   numbers of tails?

Analytically, the probability is given as

(n+m choose m) (1/2^(n+m))

so for example, if n=5 and m=7 the desired probability is

(5+7 choose 7) (1/2^(5+7)) = 0.193

I am interested in figuring out how to simulate this situation in R. I have so far,

```
coin=c("H","T")
n=5
m=7
u=replicate(10^6,sample(coin,n,repl=T))
v=replicate(10^6,sample(coin,m,repl=T))
```

but I'm not sure how to proceed in finding how often the number of tails in a given sample is equal for both u and v.

I tried using the table() function but

```
table(u)
table(v)
```

just returns the total number of heads and tails in each of the samples, combined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each replication is stored in its own column of `u` and `v`, so you need to count the number of tails in each column and compare:

```
u_ntails = colSums(u == "T")
v_ntails = colSums(v == "T")

sum(u_ntails == v_ntails) / length(u_ntails)
```